# Cucumber option not running the tag scenario from mvn cli command

Tags: maven, cucumber, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-java

I want to run particular scenario from my feature file with the below command.

> mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Smoke-Login"

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/TestRunner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>false</useUnlimitedThreads>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The below is my runner file for running the suite from pom.xml

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        publish = true,
        features = "classpath:features",glue = "stepDefinations",
        plugin = {"junit:target/cucumber-results.xml","rerun:target/rerun.txt",
                    "pretty",
                    "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json"},
        tags="@QA53",
        monochrome = true
)
public class TestRunner {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup(){
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        if (os.contains("mac")) {
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/log4j.properties");
        }
        else {
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(FileReader.getInstance().getConfigReader().getlog4jpath());
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void writeExtentReport() {
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        if (os.contains("mac")) {
        }
        else {
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my file structure in the below image.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on [a recent version of Cucumber (> 5.0)](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/release-notes/v5.0.0.md#property-based-options) the syntax is `cucumber.filter.tags=@Smoke-Login`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have this feature file specified in the runner file mentioned in the POM file. And the feature file should have the tag @Smoke-Login for the scenario u want to execute.
then u will be able to run with the below command

mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags -@Smoke-Login"